# Calculate Inverse Laplace Transform $H(s)=\frac{1}{s^4-s^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution, inverse-laplace

Calculate Inverse Laplace Transform $$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^4-s^2}$$

I am trying to solve this by convolution but I don't know how to move forward. I have come this far.

$$H(s) = \frac{1}{s^4-s^2}$$
$$h(t) = (f*g)(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$
$$F(s) = \frac{1}{s^2} \implies f(t) = t$$
$$G(s) = \frac{1}{s^2-1} \implies g(t) = \sinh(t)$$
$$h(t) = t * \sinh(t) = \int_0^t\tau \sinh(t-\tau)d\tau$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: Welcome. Posting image is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. Since you are new contributor, the images have been converted to text for once (If you can't see text, assume that conversion process is in Queue). It is advisable to get yourself trained with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that from future you can type your question self. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Another way

$$
\frac{1}{s^2(s^2-1)}=\frac{A}{s^2}+\frac{B}{s-1}+\frac{C}{s+1} = \frac{(B+C)s^3+(A+B-C)s^2-A}{s^2(s^2-1)}
$$
so we need

$$
\cases{B+C = 0\\
A+B-C=0\\
A=-1}
$$

Regarding the convolution, as  $f\circledast g = g\circledast f$ we have

$$
\int_0^t\tau \sinh(t-\tau)d\tau = \int_0^t(t-\tau) \sinh(\tau)d\tau
$$

and

$$
\int_0^t(t-\tau) \sinh(\tau)d\tau = t\int_0^t\sinh(\tau)d\tau - \int_0^t\tau \sinh(\tau)d\tau
$$

NOTE

$$
\sinh(x) = \frac 12(e^x-e^{-x})
$$

Comment: But how to i solve the intagral. I dont see how the two sides of the "=" is the same. i find it counfusing to take the integral of sin(t - tau) dtau

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Comment: Thank you! could your write the rest of the other way? i dont know how to find A, B, C

Comment: Included additional explanations.